# Why does this mongodb controller pass undefined back to route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

The app is using basic Node.js, Express, and MongoDB to return some data at different routes.

Route:

```js
router.get('/api/v1/:collection', (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const data = ApiController.getAllRecipes(req, res, next);
        console.log(data);
        res.send(data);
    } catch(error) {
        res.send(error);
    }
});
```

The methods that query the database are contained within a simple controller:

```js
module.exports = {
    getAllRecipes: async (req, res, next) => {
        try {
            req.app.db.collection(req.params.collection).find({}).toArray((error, result) => {
                if (result.length > 0) {
                    console.log(result);
                    return result;
                } else {
                    let error = new Error();
                    error.statusCode = 404;
                    error.message = 'No API results found.';
                    next(error);
                }
            });
        } catch (error) {
            next(error);
        }
    }
};
```

Inside the controller, the `console.log(result);` returns the correct data that I would like to be handled within the route file. However, the `console.log(data);` in the Route file returns `undefined`, even within the `try/catch` block.

Am I missing something in passing the data from the controller back to the route? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution! Since the controller is asynchronous, it doesn't need to return data, but rather save it to `res.locals` and execute Express' `next()` method to continue with the route.

Updated Route:

```js
router.get('/api/v:versionNumber/:collection', ApiController.getAllRecipes, (req, res, next) => {
    res.send(res.locals.results);
});
```

Updated controller:

```js
getAllRecipes: async (req, res, next) => {
        try {
            req.app.db.collection(req.params.collection).find({}).toArray((error, result) => {
                if (result.length > 0) {
                    res.locals.results = result;
                    next();
                } else {
                    let error = new Error();
                    error.statusCode = 404;
                    error.message = 'No API results found.';
                    next(error);
                }
            });
        } catch (error) {
            next(error);
        }
    }
```